# Angular activatedRoute paramMap not unsubscribing when there is a switchMap operator inside

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to subscribe to the activatedRoute and read the params only the first time (e.g- ngOnInit). I am using a switchMap inside to get data from the server using the `id` from the params.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.paramMap
    .pipe(
      take(1),
      filter((params) => params.has('id')),
      switchMap((params) => {
        this.loading = true
        return this.jobReportService.get(+params.get('id'))
      }),
      tap((jobReport) => {
        this.layoutForm.setValue(jobReport)
        this.loading = false
      }),
    )
    .subscribe()
}
```

Problem is when I am trying to navigate away from the component, the paramMap subscription is still active (even though I used `take(1)`) and that triggers another switchMap operation causing the API call with `undefined`. That results an HTTP error and halts the navigation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe your component gets rerendered and fires ngOnInit again? Stackblitz example could help a lot

Comment: @igor_c Thank you. Your comment made me investigate and found that it was actually a silly mistake of mine - I imported the module route in wrong order so all the other routes were replaced and was loading this component for all the other routes.